# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with Ajax after taking site to SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ssl, cross-domain, cors

We are using Ruby 2.1.2 with Rails 3.2.14.
We are getting the following error on browser's console for ajax requests after we moved our site to SSL.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sitename.com/xxx/xx?id=xx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

We've tried adding

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
crossDomain: true
```

but no effect. Here is the ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {id: id}, 
            url: path+id,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            crossDomain: true,           
            success: function(data) { }
});
```

Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

You have to set headers on server side. Not on the client. The simplest way will be use something like this in your ApplicationController:

```
after_filter  :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexander's answer was correct. However, it is not recommended to allow all domains to access your api (unless it's public) [See CORS section of OWASP Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Rails 5 Implementation

```
after_action :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'mysite.example.com'
end
```